# libpcap: pcap_breakloop() causing memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, pthreads, libpcap

While working with Linux *pthreads* and *libpcap* I noticed some weird behavior when using `pcap_breakloop`. **My goal is the following:**
Opening a new thread that will run `pcap_loop` and deal with captured packets, while the main thread will do other stuff. When the a signal (SIGINT) is received, or when it's time to exit, a global variable will be set and the main thread will issue `pcap_breakloop` to end the second thread and then finish itself.

The idea might still need some working, but the strange behavior I noticed was:

When we create a `bpf_program` structure and compile it with `pcap_compile`, to further use it as a filter on the capture, once we exit the loop using `pcap_breakloop` there is a memory leak of 8 bytes (both `pcap_freecode` and `pcap_close` being called). That is true **even when not using threads** (as can be seem on the modified `sniffex.c` *libpcap* example). **The same code, without a filter (no `pcap_compile` call or `bpf_program`) exits without a memory leak**.

Is that memory leak something to be expected from *libpcap* like some memory leaks I've seem on other libraries (`gtk` for example)? Is it something the library will deal with later? Or is there something wrong on my code I can't see?

Below are the code examples: The one using *pthreads* and the modified *sniffex* example with `pcap_breakloop` (I also included a `diff` from the original *sniffex* and the modified one, since the code is quite large, but the difference is really small):

**Example with *pthreads*:**

```
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

int CLOSE_PROGRAM = 0;
int CAPTURE_SETUP_SUCCESS = 0;
pcap_t *handler;    //pcap_t handler and filter structure are globals so we can free them from other
struct bpf_program fp;  //functions

//Prototypes
void INT_Handler(int signum);   //signal handler
void capture_loop(unsigned char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const unsigned char *packet);  //pcap_loop function
void *thread_entrypoint(void *data);    //the entry point for the second thread

void INT_Handler(int signum){
    printf("Interrupt Signal Received\n");
    CLOSE_PROGRAM = 1;
}

void capture_loop(unsigned char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const unsigned char *packet){
    printf("Captured Packet\n");
    //Process packet
}

void *thread_entrypoint(void *data){
    //We can't cancel the thread before we free libpcap stuff
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL);

    char error[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    char filter_exp[] = "ip";
    bpf_u_int32 mask;
    bpf_u_int32 net;

    char *dev = pcap_lookupdev(error);
    if(NULL == dev){
        printf("Failed to look up device!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    if(pcap_lookupnet(dev, &net, &mask, error) == -1){
        printf("Failed to look up netmask: %s\n", error);
        net = 0;
        mask = 0;
    }

    printf("Opening live capture on device %s\n", dev);
    handler = pcap_open_live(dev, 1518, 0, 1000, error);
    if(NULL == handler){
        printf("Failed to open live capture!\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if(pcap_compile(handler, &fp, filter_exp, 0, net?net:PCAP_NETMASK_UNKNOWN) == -1){
        printf("Failed to compiler filter!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    if(pcap_setfilter(handler, &fp) == -1){
        printf("Failed to install filter!\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    CAPTURE_SETUP_SUCCESS = 1;
    pcap_loop(handler, 0, capture_loop, NULL);

    pcap_freecode(&fp);
    pcap_close(handler);

    printf("Capture end\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    pthread_t capture_thread;

    pthread_create(&capture_thread, NULL, &thread_entrypoint, NULL);

    signal(SIGINT, &INT_Handler);

    while(0 == CLOSE_PROGRAM){
        //Wait for SIGINT
    }

    if(1 == CAPTURE_SETUP_SUCCESS){
        pcap_breakloop(handler);
    }
    pthread_join(capture_thread, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

**Modified *sniffex* example:**

```
/*
 * sniffex.c
 *
 * Sniffer example of TCP/IP packet capture using libpcap.
 * 
 * Version 0.1.1 (2005-07-05)
 * Copyright (c) 2005 The Tcpdump Group
 *
 * This software is intended to be used as a practical example and 
 * demonstration of the libpcap library; available at:
 * http://www.tcpdump.org/
 *
 ****************************************************************************
 *
 * This software is a modification of Tim Carstens' "sniffer.c"
 * demonstration source code, released as follows:
 * 
 * sniffer.c
 * Copyright (c) 2002 Tim Carstens
 * 2002-01-07
 * Demonstration of using libpcap
 * timcarst -at- yahoo -dot- com
 * 
 * "sniffer.c" is distributed under these terms:
 * 
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * 4. The name "Tim Carstens" may not be used to endorse or promote
 *    products derived from this software without prior written permission
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE REGENTS AND CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS'' AND
 * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
 * ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE REGENTS OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
 * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
 * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS
 * OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
 * HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
 * LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY
 * OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF
 * SUCH DAMAGE.
 * <end of "sniffer.c" terms>
 *
 * This software, "sniffex.c", is a derivative work of "sniffer.c" and is
 * covered by the following terms:
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 * 1. Because this is a derivative work, you must comply with the "sniffer.c"
 *    terms reproduced above.
 * 2. Redistributions of source code must retain the Tcpdump Group copyright
 *    notice at the top of this source file, this list of conditions and the
 *    following disclaimer.
 * 3. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * 4. The names "tcpdump" or "libpcap" may not be used to endorse or promote
 *    products derived from this software without prior written permission.
 *
 * THERE IS ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY FOR THIS PROGRAM.
 * BECAUSE THE PROGRAM IS LICENSED FREE OF CHARGE, THERE IS NO WARRANTY
 * FOR THE PROGRAM, TO THE EXTENT PERMITTED BY APPLICABLE LAW.  EXCEPT WHEN
 * OTHERWISE STATED IN WRITING THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND/OR OTHER PARTIES
 * PROVIDE THE PROGRAM "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED
 * OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  THE ENTIRE RISK AS
 * TO THE QUALITY AND PERFORMANCE OF THE PROGRAM IS WITH YOU.  SHOULD THE
 * PROGRAM PROVE DEFECTIVE, YOU ASSUME THE COST OF ALL NECESSARY SERVICING,
 * REPAIR OR CORRECTION.
 * 
 * IN NO EVENT UNLESS REQUIRED BY APPLICABLE LAW OR AGREED TO IN WRITING
 * WILL ANY COPYRIGHT HOLDER, OR ANY OTHER PARTY WHO MAY MODIFY AND/OR
 * REDISTRIBUTE THE PROGRAM AS PERMITTED ABOVE, BE LIABLE TO YOU FOR DAMAGES,
 * INCLUDING ANY GENERAL, SPECIAL, INCIDENTAL OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES ARISING
 * OUT OF THE USE OR INABILITY TO USE THE PROGRAM (INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED
 * TO LOSS OF DATA OR DATA BEING RENDERED INACCURATE OR LOSSES SUSTAINED BY
 * YOU OR THIRD PARTIES OR A FAILURE OF THE PROGRAM TO OPERATE WITH ANY OTHER
 * PROGRAMS), EVEN IF SUCH HOLDER OR OTHER PARTY HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGES.
 * <end of "sniffex.c" terms>
 * 
 ****************************************************************************
 *
 * Below is an excerpt from an email from Guy Harris on the tcpdump-workers
 * mail list when someone asked, "How do I get the length of the TCP
 * payload?" Guy Harris' slightly snipped response (edited by him to
 * speak of the IPv4 header length and TCP data offset without referring
 * to bitfield structure members) is reproduced below:
 * 
 * The Ethernet size is always 14 bytes.
 * 
 * <snip>...</snip>
 *
 * In fact, you *MUST* assume the Ethernet header is 14 bytes, *and*, if 
 * you're using structures, you must use structures where the members 
 * always have the same size on all platforms, because the sizes of the 
 * fields in Ethernet - and IP, and TCP, and... - headers are defined by 
 * the protocol specification, not by the way a particular platform's C 
 * compiler works.)
 *
 * The IP header size, in bytes, is the value of the IP header length,
 * as extracted from the "ip_vhl" field of "struct sniff_ip" with
 * the "IP_HL()" macro, times 4 ("times 4" because it's in units of
 * 4-byte words).  If that value is less than 20 - i.e., if the value
 * extracted with "IP_HL()" is less than 5 - you have a malformed
 * IP datagram.
 *
 * The TCP header size, in bytes, is the value of the TCP data offset,
 * as extracted from the "th_offx2" field of "struct sniff_tcp" with
 * the "TH_OFF()" macro, times 4 (for the same reason - 4-byte words).
 * If that value is less than 20 - i.e., if the value extracted with
 * "TH_OFF()" is less than 5 - you have a malformed TCP segment.
 *
 * So, to find the IP header in an Ethernet packet, look 14 bytes after 
 * the beginning of the packet data.  To find the TCP header, look 
 * "IP_HL(ip)*4" bytes after the beginning of the IP header.  To find the
 * TCP payload, look "TH_OFF(tcp)*4" bytes after the beginning of the TCP
 * header.
 * 
 * To find out how much payload there is:
 *
 * Take the IP *total* length field - "ip_len" in "struct sniff_ip" 
 * - and, first, check whether it's less than "IP_HL(ip)*4" (after
 * you've checked whether "IP_HL(ip)" is >= 5).  If it is, you have
 * a malformed IP datagram.
 *
 * Otherwise, subtract "IP_HL(ip)*4" from it; that gives you the length
 * of the TCP segment, including the TCP header.  If that's less than
 * "TH_OFF(tcp)*4" (after you've checked whether "TH_OFF(tcp)" is >= 5),
 * you have a malformed TCP segment.
 *
 * Otherwise, subtract "TH_OFF(tcp)*4" from it; that gives you the
 * length of the TCP payload.
 *
 * Note that you also need to make sure that you don't go past the end 
 * of the captured data in the packet - you might, for example, have a 
 * 15-byte Ethernet packet that claims to contain an IP datagram, but if 
 * it's 15 bytes, it has only one byte of Ethernet payload, which is too 
 * small for an IP header.  The length of the captured data is given in 
 * the "caplen" field in the "struct pcap_pkthdr"; it might be less than 
 * the length of the packet, if you're capturing with a snapshot length 
 * other than a value >= the maximum packet size.
 * <end of response>
 * 
 ****************************************************************************
 * 
 * Example compiler command-line for GCC:
 *   gcc -Wall -o sniffex sniffex.c -lpcap
 * 
 ****************************************************************************
 *
 * Code Comments
 *
 * This section contains additional information and explanations regarding
 * comments in the source code. It serves as documentaion and rationale
 * for why the code is written as it is without hindering readability, as it
 * might if it were placed along with the actual code inline. References in
 * the code appear as footnote notation (e.g. [1]).
 *
 * 1. Ethernet headers are always exactly 14 bytes, so we define this
 * explicitly with "#define". Since some compilers might pad structures to a
 * multiple of 4 bytes - some versions of GCC for ARM may do this -
 * "sizeof (struct sniff_ethernet)" isn't used.
 * 
 * 2. Check the link-layer type of the device that's being opened to make
 * sure it's Ethernet, since that's all we handle in this example. Other
 * link-layer types may have different length headers (see [1]).
 *
 * 3. This is the filter expression that tells libpcap which packets we're
 * interested in (i.e. which packets to capture). Since this source example
 * focuses on IP and TCP, we use the expression "ip", so we know we'll only
 * encounter IP packets. The capture filter syntax, along with some
 * examples, is documented in the tcpdump man page under "expression."
 * Below are a few simple examples:
 *
 * Expression           Description
 * ----------           -----------
 * ip                   Capture all IP packets.
 * tcp                  Capture only TCP packets.
 * tcp port 80          Capture only TCP packets with a port equal to 80.
 * ip host 10.1.2.3     Capture all IP packets to or from host 10.1.2.3.
 *
 ****************************************************************************
 *
 */

#define APP_NAME        "sniffex"
#define APP_DESC        "Sniffer example using libpcap"
#define APP_COPYRIGHT   "Copyright (c) 2005 The Tcpdump Group"
#define APP_DISCLAIMER  "THERE IS ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY FOR THIS PROGRAM."

#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

pcap_t *handle;             /* packet capture handle */

/* default snap length (maximum bytes per packet to capture) */
#define SNAP_LEN 1518

/* ethernet headers are always exactly 14 bytes [1] */
#define SIZE_ETHERNET 14

/* Ethernet addresses are 6 bytes */
#define ETHER_ADDR_LEN  6

/* Ethernet header */
struct sniff_ethernet {
        u_char  ether_dhost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];    /* destination host address */
        u_char  ether_shost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];    /* source host address */
        u_short ether_type;                     /* IP? ARP? RARP? etc */
};

/* IP header */
struct sniff_ip {
        u_char  ip_vhl;                 /* version << 4 | header length >> 2 */
        u_char  ip_tos;                 /* type of service */
        u_short ip_len;                 /* total length */
        u_short ip_id;                  /* identification */
        u_short ip_off;                 /* fragment offset field */
        #define IP_RF 0x8000            /* reserved fragment flag */
        #define IP_DF 0x4000            /* dont fragment flag */
        #define IP_MF 0x2000            /* more fragments flag */
        #define IP_OFFMASK 0x1fff       /* mask for fragmenting bits */
        u_char  ip_ttl;                 /* time to live */
        u_char  ip_p;                   /* protocol */
        u_short ip_sum;                 /* checksum */
        struct  in_addr ip_src,ip_dst;  /* source and dest address */
};
#define IP_HL(ip)               (((ip)->ip_vhl) & 0x0f)
#define IP_V(ip)                (((ip)->ip_vhl) >> 4)

/* TCP header */
typedef u_int tcp_seq;

struct sniff_tcp {
        u_short th_sport;               /* source port */
        u_short th_dport;               /* destination port */
        tcp_seq th_seq;                 /* sequence number */
        tcp_seq th_ack;                 /* acknowledgement number */
        u_char  th_offx2;               /* data offset, rsvd */
#define TH_OFF(th)      (((th)->th_offx2 & 0xf0) >> 4)
        u_char  th_flags;
        #define TH_FIN  0x01
        #define TH_SYN  0x02
        #define TH_RST  0x04
        #define TH_PUSH 0x08
        #define TH_ACK  0x10
        #define TH_URG  0x20
        #define TH_ECE  0x40
        #define TH_CWR  0x80
        #define TH_FLAGS        (TH_FIN|TH_SYN|TH_RST|TH_ACK|TH_URG|TH_ECE|TH_CWR)
        u_short th_win;                 /* window */
        u_short th_sum;                 /* checksum */
        u_short th_urp;                 /* urgent pointer */
};

void
got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet);

void
print_payload(const u_char *payload, int len);

void
print_hex_ascii_line(const u_char *payload, int len, int offset);

void
print_app_banner(void);

void
print_app_usage(void);

/*
 * app name/banner
 */
void
print_app_banner(void)
{

    printf("%s - %s\n", APP_NAME, APP_DESC);
    printf("%s\n", APP_COPYRIGHT);
    printf("%s\n", APP_DISCLAIMER);
    printf("\n");

return;
}

/*
 * print help text
 */
void
print_app_usage(void)
{

    printf("Usage: %s [interface]\n", APP_NAME);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Options:\n");
    printf("    interface    Listen on <interface> for packets.\n");
    printf("\n");

return;
}

/*
 * print data in rows of 16 bytes: offset   hex   ascii
 *
 * 00000   47 45 54 20 2f 20 48 54  54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d 0a   GET / HTTP/1.1..
 */
void
print_hex_ascii_line(const u_char *payload, int len, int offset)
{

    int i;
    int gap;
    const u_char *ch;

    /* offset */
    printf("%05d   ", offset);

    /* hex */
    ch = payload;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%02x ", *ch);
        ch++;
        /* print extra space after 8th byte for visual aid */
        if (i == 7)
            printf(" ");
    }
    /* print space to handle line less than 8 bytes */
    if (len < 8)
        printf(" ");

    /* fill hex gap with spaces if not full line */
    if (len < 16) {
        gap = 16 - len;
        for (i = 0; i < gap; i++) {
            printf("   ");
        }
    }
    printf("   ");

    /* ascii (if printable) */
    ch = payload;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (isprint(*ch))
            printf("%c", *ch);
        else
            printf(".");
        ch++;
    }

    printf("\n");

return;
}

/*
 * print packet payload data (avoid printing binary data)
 */
void
print_payload(const u_char *payload, int len)
{

    int len_rem = len;
    int line_width = 16;            /* number of bytes per line */
    int line_len;
    int offset = 0;                 /* zero-based offset counter */
    const u_char *ch = payload;

    if (len <= 0)
        return;

    /* data fits on one line */
    if (len <= line_width) {
        print_hex_ascii_line(ch, len, offset);
        return;
    }

    /* data spans multiple lines */
    for ( ;; ) {
        /* compute current line length */
        line_len = line_width % len_rem;
        /* print line */
        print_hex_ascii_line(ch, line_len, offset);
        /* compute total remaining */
        len_rem = len_rem - line_len;
        /* shift pointer to remaining bytes to print */
        ch = ch + line_len;
        /* add offset */
        offset = offset + line_width;
        /* check if we have line width chars or less */
        if (len_rem <= line_width) {
            /* print last line and get out */
            print_hex_ascii_line(ch, len_rem, offset);
            break;
        }
    }

return;
}

/*
 * dissect/print packet
 */
void
got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet)
{

    pcap_breakloop(handle);

    static int count = 1;                   /* packet counter */

    /* declare pointers to packet headers */
    const struct sniff_ethernet *ethernet;  /* The ethernet header [1] */
    const struct sniff_ip *ip;              /* The IP header */
    const struct sniff_tcp *tcp;            /* The TCP header */
    const char *payload;                    /* Packet payload */

    int size_ip;
    int size_tcp;
    int size_payload;

    printf("\nPacket number %d:\n", count);
    count++;

    /* define ethernet header */
    ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(packet);

    /* define/compute ip header offset */
    ip = (struct sniff_ip*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET);
    size_ip = IP_HL(ip)*4;
    if (size_ip < 20) {
        printf("   * Invalid IP header length: %u bytes\n", size_ip);
        return;
    }

    /* print source and destination IP addresses */
    printf("       From: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src));
    printf("         To: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst));

    /* determine protocol */    
    switch(ip->ip_p) {
        case IPPROTO_TCP:
            printf("   Protocol: TCP\n");
            break;
        case IPPROTO_UDP:
            printf("   Protocol: UDP\n");
            return;
        case IPPROTO_ICMP:
            printf("   Protocol: ICMP\n");
            return;
        case IPPROTO_IP:
            printf("   Protocol: IP\n");
            return;
        default:
            printf("   Protocol: unknown\n");
            return;
    }

    /*
     *  OK, this packet is TCP.
     */

    /* define/compute tcp header offset */
    tcp = (struct sniff_tcp*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip);
    size_tcp = TH_OFF(tcp)*4;
    if (size_tcp < 20) {
        printf("   * Invalid TCP header length: %u bytes\n", size_tcp);
        return;
    }

    printf("   Src port: %d\n", ntohs(tcp->th_sport));
    printf("   Dst port: %d\n", ntohs(tcp->th_dport));

    /* define/compute tcp payload (segment) offset */
    payload = (u_char *)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip + size_tcp);

    /* compute tcp payload (segment) size */
    size_payload = ntohs(ip->ip_len) - (size_ip + size_tcp);

    /*
     * Print payload data; it might be binary, so don't just
     * treat it as a string.
     */
    if (size_payload > 0) {
        printf("   Payload (%d bytes):\n", size_payload);
        print_payload(payload, size_payload);
    }

return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char *dev = NULL;           /* capture device name */
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];      /* error buffer */

    char filter_exp[] = "ip";       /* filter expression [3] */
    struct bpf_program fp;          /* compiled filter program (expression) */
    bpf_u_int32 mask;           /* subnet mask */
    bpf_u_int32 net;            /* ip */
    int num_packets = 10;           /* number of packets to capture */

    print_app_banner();

    /* check for capture device name on command-line */
    if (argc == 2) {
        dev = argv[1];
    }
    else if (argc > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: unrecognized command-line options\n\n");
        print_app_usage();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        /* find a capture device if not specified on command-line */
        dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
        if (dev == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find default device: %s\n",
                errbuf);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /* get network number and mask associated with capture device */
    if (pcap_lookupnet(dev, &net, &mask, errbuf) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get netmask for device %s: %s\n",
            dev, errbuf);
        net = 0;
        mask = 0;
    }

    /* print capture info */
    printf("Device: %s\n", dev);
    printf("Number of packets: %d\n", num_packets);
    printf("Filter expression: %s\n", filter_exp);

    /* open capture device */
    handle = pcap_open_live(dev, SNAP_LEN, 1, 1000, errbuf);
    if (handle == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* make sure we're capturing on an Ethernet device [2] */
    if (pcap_datalink(handle) != DLT_EN10MB) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s is not an Ethernet\n", dev);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* compile the filter expression */
    if (pcap_compile(handle, &fp, filter_exp, 0, net) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't parse filter %s: %s\n",
            filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* apply the compiled filter */
    if (pcap_setfilter(handle, &fp) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't install filter %s: %s\n",
            filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* now we can set our callback function */
    pcap_loop(handle, num_packets, got_packet, NULL);

    /* cleanup */
    pcap_freecode(&fp);
    pcap_close(handle);

    printf("\nCapture complete.\n");

return 0;
}
```

**`diff` from original *sniffex* and modified *sniffex* codes:**

```
209a210,211
> pcap_t *handle;               /* packet capture handle */
> 
420a423,424
>   pcap_breakloop(handle);
> 
508d511
<   pcap_t *handle;             /* packet capture handle */
```

**Valgrind message for the multithread code:**

```
==2734== 
==2734== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2734==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==2734==   total heap usage: 96 allocs, 95 frees, 82,123 bytes allocated
==2734== 
==2734== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2734==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2734==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2734==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2734==    still reachable: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==2734==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2734== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==2734== 
==2734== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2734== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==2734== ERROR SUMMARY: 9 errors from 9 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**Valgrind message for modified sniffex code:**

```
==2756== 
==2756== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2756==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==2756==   total heap usage: 97 allocs, 96 frees, 83,427 bytes allocated
==2756== 
==2756== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2756==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2756==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2756==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2756==    still reachable: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==2756==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2756== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==2756== 
==2756== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2756== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==2756== ERROR SUMMARY: 9 errors from 9 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like this was indeed a bug on `libpcap`. According to this [bug report](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/issues/109) on their GitHub page, `pcap_compile` was causing some memory leak very similar to the one I experienced on my codes.

```
==1505== still reachable: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
```

Exactly 8 bytes in 1 blocks, like on my `valgrind` reports. There were comments saying the latest master branch version already fixed the bug.

Currently, Ubuntu's repositories have `libpcap 1.7.4-2`, while the latest release on GitHub is `libpcap 1.8.1` apparently. I was using a VM to test the codes, since I needed to run `valgrind` as root to get the `libpcap` live capture working. I purged the currently installed `libpcap` library, cloned the latest version, built it from source and symlinked it as the older version on `/usr/lib` to test it again on the VM with the latest release.

Running the same code (both the multithreaded example and the modified sniffex code) resulted in a report with absolutely **zero** memory leaks!

It apparently was related to `flex` and not `pcap` itself, but in case anyone runs into the same mysterious memory leak, and is bothered by having it, download the latest `pcap` version and it should be fixed.

Thanks for @Kamiccolo for pointing the possibility of it being a bug! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
==2756== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2756==    still reachable: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
```

The memory is still reachable, so there's no memory leak here.  If you really care about it, do what valgrind tells you and run with `--leak-check=full` to get full details of who allocated the memory and who is responsible for freeing it.